# SugarCRM logic hook Migrating from CE to Professional issue

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I was using SugarCRM 6.8 CE and my logic hooks was working as expected . However when i switched to SugarPro-Full-7.8.2.0 .The logic hooks is not working at all. I am following the documentation http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/ . My code is given below

**SugarPro-Full-7.8.2.0/custom/modules/Accounts/logic_hooks.php**

```
<?php

$hook_array['after_ui_frame'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_ui_frame'][] = Array(2, 'After Relationship Add','custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/LogicHooks/account_hooks.php','AccountHooks','generateOWQ');

?>
```

**SugarPro-Full-7.8.2.0/custom/modules/Accounts/Ext/LogicHooks/account_hooks.php**

```
<?php
    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class AccountHooks{

        function generateOWQ($event, $arguments){
           //my logic
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: any error message

Comment: No errors i have checked the logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `after_ui_frame` hook is a legacy MVC hook that does not apply to the *Accounts* module in Sugar 7.

As the [documentation](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/Application_Hooks/after_ui_frame/) points out:

> The `after_ui_frame` hook executes after the frame has been invoked and before the footer has been invoked **for modules in backward compatibility mode**.

(*emphasis mine*)

Most Sugar 7 modules, including *Accounts*, use Sugar's [sidecar javascript framework](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/User_Interface/Sidecar/) for building the user-interface on the client-side.
Those modules do *not* run in **b**ack**w**ards-**c**ompatiblity mode and do *not* call this hook. Only non-sidecar modules with `#bwc` in their URL do.

Based on what *your logic* has to do, consider using a different hook, e.g. [`after_relationship_add`](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/after_relationship_add/), [`after_retrieve`](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/after_retrieve/), [etc.](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/)

If your code is supposed to also modify the UI, you probably have to do things client-side, e.g. by [extending views](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/05/28/extending-view-javascript-in-sugarcrm-7/).